# Hide keyboard of mobile device in input text box

Tags: jquery, html, input, keyboard

I'm working on a quick mock of a mobile app in form of a website. I have a barcode scanner that works like a keyboard and can enter text when scanning a barcode. Now I want a textbox on the website that has the cursor in it but does not show the default on-screen keyboard of the mobile device.

How can I hide the on-screen keyboard of a mobile device in such a html input box but have the cursor in that text box so that i can accept input from other external keyboards?

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding the following to the input field

`<input type="text" id="barcode" onfocus="blur();"/>`

Unfortunately on some, not all, mobile devices, when you hide the soft keyboard the focus will be lost for said text field. This is a work around and hopefully works for your application needs.

Comment: this does not work. `blur()` simply removes focus from the element and hence I cannot read its value anymore. Also, it does not make the textbox invisible. The workaround that I use now is to set the position out of the range: `style='position: absolute; top: -100px'`

Comment: Yeah I wasn't going to bet on it, others have had luck with such additions. However I'm glad you found a solution!